# How to subtract 1 number multiple times and put on new list?

Tags: c#, for-loop, logic

*Edit*: thanks for the fkn -3 downvotes, this is really going to encourage ameteurs like me into getting into c#, im sorry im not a fkn expert with a phd in computer science, i thought this forum/website was about engaging in a community and work together to learn new things while being helped/tutored by other people that love this field, boy was i wrong, this forums is just filled with hatred for people like me, i guess i will try to find another forum that's not so unforgiving.

This program grabs a number from a list (9.9) and in a new list im having trouble subtracting it by 2 so that in my 'for' loop it add's a list of 5 numbers.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
  {
     rList2.Add(9.9 - 2);
  }
```

But here's the problem, the new list's contents are:

```
7.9

7.9

7.9

7.9

7.9
```

when it should be:

```
9.9

7.9

5.9

3.9

1.9
```

Wondering what I'm doing wrong :/

Summary: need a function that subtracts 1 number (9.9) by itself by 2, 5 times.

Comment: Why would you ever expect the value of `9.9 - 2` to be anything but 7.9? You need to include `i` in your formula for it to have an effect...

Comment: I'm sorry for your bad experience. I don't find it to be off-topic at all. But it's also not completely clear what you're asking. Make it explicitly clear what the result should be. And remove your edit and make it a comment; it's not relevant to the question..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to track previous value

Like this

```
var val=9.9;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{

    rList2.Add(val);
    val -= 2;
}
```

<kbd>**[`DEMO`](http://ideone.com/9QuyT3)**</kbd>

Comment: @AdanChristo you are weclome :) don't forget to mark it accepted :)

Comment: any reason for downvote that i missed ?

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    rList2.Add(9.9 - 2.0 * i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do this one.

```
int val=9.9;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    rList2.Add(val);
    val = val - 2;
}
```